# Crash on contentResolver.openInputStream(uri) getting security permission denied

Tags: android

App getting crash and logged issue -

```
Caused by java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.apps.docs.storagebackend.StorageBackendContentProvider from ProcessRecord (pid=23306, uid=10207) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

i am using this code:

```
   val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
} else {
    intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
}
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

//Make sure to only display images that can be opened as an inputstream so we can upload them
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
}

startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
```

Content resolver used in `JobIntent` service:

```
contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
```

How can we resolved this isue?

Comment: perhaps you are not waiting for the answer on the permissionrequest before you perform the action?

Comment: @JoachimHaglund i am using JobIntent service for upload image in background and crashing point is
contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46916992/having-trouble-implementing-action-open-document-to-my-project

Comment: not getting proper cause of error! i an using only gallery for select images but showing com.google.android.apps.docs.storagebackend docs in error??