# Android "storing" and "reusing" obtained URIs

Tags: android, uri, android-permissions, android-fileprovider

My app collects media through an ACTION_PICK Intent to get
`android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`

type of content. When I retrieve the URI of the content I want, It works great and I can view it with:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, myURI)
intent.setDataAndType(myURI,contentResolver.getType(myURI))
intent.addFlags(FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
startActivity(intent)
```

I store the Uri with `Uri.toString` method, and as soon as I close the activity and open it again, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10315 does not have permission to content://com.miui.gallery.open/raw/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FDCIM%2FCamera%2FVID_20200814_214253.mp4 [user 0]
```

and further down also:

```
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService.checkGrantUriPermission(UriGrantsManagerService.java:1192)
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService.checkGrantUriPermissionFromIntent(UriGrantsManagerService.java:579)
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService.grantUriPermissionFromIntent(UriGrantsManagerService.java:618)
    at com.android.server.uri.UriGrantsManagerService$LocalService.grantUriPermissionFromIntent(UriGrantsManagerService.java:1392)
```

Ideally I would get the file path of the media and generate the URI from file through a fileProvider, but I haven't found a way of getting an absolute path from ContentURIs.

Read through https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html which explains better what is happening, so how can I reuse or store a file I retrieved through its URI? Can I retrieve a file path instead of a URI in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I store the Uri with Uri.toString method

That is not going to work. Your rights to the content obtained from `ACTION_PICK` are [very short-lived](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html). (note: this link is to a newer version of my blog post that you linked to in the question)

> Ideally I would get the file path of the media

That also is not going to work. There is no requirement for `ACTION_PICK` or similar actions to return anything that relates to the filesystem, let alone to some file that you could access directly. In your specific case, the `MediaStore` has greater access than you do, so things that you find in the `MediaStore` may not be accessible, even if you query for the semi-deprecated `DATA` column to try to find a path. Plus, the implementation of `ACTION_PICK` that the user chooses may not return a `MediaStore` `Uri` anyway.

If you need to be able to select a piece of content, persist its `Uri`, and use that `Uri` to work with the content later, you need to:

- Use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` instead of `ACTION_PICK`
- Call `takePersistableUriPermissions()` on a `ContentResolver`, passing in the `Uri` that you get

Now, you have long-term access to the content... assuming that the user does not do something dramatic like delete it.

Comment: Not going to lie, I was crossing my fingers that CommonsWare, author of the article that described best my situation, would reply, and here it is! - This definitely works, users will have to adapt to using the documentProvider to select media but it seems to be the only working way

Comment: and also when calling `takePersistableUriPermissions()` make sure you're setting the appropriate flags as you explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46917241/2445763)

Comment: There is another method using DocumentsContract to get the display name of the files, and then querying the MediaStore for that display name. I have tested it for Android 4, 9, and 11 and have not ran into issues yet.

Comment: @JohnGlen: I would imagine that you would start getting problems once you have more than one file with the same display name. This also is not a general replacement for `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, though it might hold up for media content.