# Android 11 - How to access android/data/an app directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-11, scoped-storage, saf

I want to access Chrome browser directory in android/data and then copy files(TXT) From assets to that folder

1.how to get permission In Android 11

2.after getting permission How to copy any file from asset folder to that directory

Please give me an code that works like this

[Image First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DvOE.jpg)

[Image Second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEzYs.jpg)

App link above screenshot: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.tsoml.graphicssettings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507100/accessing-android-data-folder-directory?noredirect=1#comment121087591_68507100

Comment: There is no answer sir

Comment: Why do you think you need permission? And what did you try? And what would be full path? What are the problems you encountered?

Comment: I am making a GFX tool for pubg I want to replace it's file with my files stored in assest folder.

Comment: You did not answer any of my questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512009/how-to-copy-files-to-android-data-other-app-directory-in-android-11

Comment: Hi, i dont want to discourage you, but this is not good post. You are asking "give me working code of specific feature of this app". 

First, you need to do research. Then try few codes. If things do not work, state what you tried and what did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If your app holds `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission it can access `Android/obb` directory.

and for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66466205/9119669)