# How to let user pick a folder on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms

In my mobile app, I would like to show a GUI where user can browse the folders on their device, select a folder and return folder path to my app. Is there built in support or a nice library, or do I need to implement such GUI myself?

I am using Xamarin Forms and already searched nuget.org but did not find anything that would do the job. If there are any iOS-specific or Android-specific solutions, that would be very helpful. I am perfectly happy to integrate Java or Swift library into the app to get a nice GUI.

**Edit**
I understand that parts of the filesystem are restricted by the operating system, and I am fine with that. The question is about not having to write the GUI from scratch.

Comment: The folder path you can return by URI. About folders check this one
[How do some apps reach the contents of ".../Android/..." sub-folders on Android 11 without root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65967690/how-do-some-apps-reach-the-contents-of-android-sub-folders-on-android)

Comment: Thank you, Spectator. This is very interesting reading with a lot of useful info. I appreciate it. Though at the moment, I am looking for a nice gui.

Comment: For Android have a look at Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: @blackapps Thank you.

Comment: In iOS, you could build [Document Browser-Based App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/building_a_document_browser-based_app) to do so. If you already had an app, [UIDocumentPickerViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller) may help.