# WhatsApp Status Save In Android 11 or above

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

Please guide me how to access whatsapp status folder in android 11?
I have seen status saver apps in play store that doesn't ask for any special permission but are still able to show statuses?
Tell me how can I access WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses folder in android 11?

Comment: honestly what's wrong with this question that It deservs a downvote

Comment: Can you please paste the link of app ? As far as I know it is not possible.

Comment: how do you know it is not possible? Does android 11 limit access to android/media folder?

Comment: Yes correct, without permission any app can not access the media files from external storage. If you can give play store link then we can find exactly how it is working and I can more comment on it.

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127116/access-hidden-folders-in-flutter-for-android-11
You can check in question that user asking for same thing in visual form

Answer (score 13):

You can solve it using the DocumentTreeIntent if you make it allow permission for the WhatsApp folder explicitly for android 11  here is how you can do that.

```
     if (Constants.isPackageInstalled(getActivity(), "com.whatsapp")) {


        Intent intent;
        StorageManager sm = (StorageManager) getActivity().getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);
        String statusDir = getWhatsupFolder();
        String str = "android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 29) {
            intent = sm.getPrimaryStorageVolume().createOpenDocumentTreeIntent();
            String scheme = ((Uri) intent.getParcelableExtra(str)).toString().replace("/root/", "/document/");
            String stringBuilder = scheme +
                    "%3A" +
                    statusDir;
            intent.putExtra(str, Uri.parse(stringBuilder));

        } else {
            intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE");
            intent.putExtra(str, Uri.parse(statusDir));
        }
        intent.addFlags(2);
        intent.addFlags(1);
        intent.addFlags(128);
        intent.addFlags(64);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        return;
    }
```

before using this code you must check if WhatsApp is installed or not so the first check is for that here is the code for that.

```
 try {

        context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
       
     }
```

after granting permission you must retrieve files via this code

```
 private DocumentFile[] getFromSdcard() {
    DocumentFile fromTreeUri = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(requireContext().getApplicationContext(), Uri.parse(namedataprefs));
    if (fromTreeUri != null && fromTreeUri.exists() && fromTreeUri.isDirectory() && fromTreeUri.canRead() && fromTreeUri.canWrite()) {
        return fromTreeUri.listFiles();
    }
    return null;
}

DocumentFile[] allFiles = getFromSdcard();
//to get signal file path
String path = allFiles[0].getUri().toString();
```

you can get further details about document tree intent from the below code its just for understanding purposes

Ref : [How to check which StorageVolume we have access to, and which we don't?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657639/how-to-check-which-storagevolume-we-have-access-to-and-which-we-dont)

```
    requestAccessButton.setOnClickListener {
        storageVolumes = storageManager.storageVolumes
        val primaryVolume = storageManager.primaryStorageVolume
        val intent = primaryVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
    }
}

private fun checkAccessToStorageVolumes() {
    val storageVolumePathsWeHaveAccessTo = HashSet<String>()
    val persistedUriPermissions = contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions
    persistedUriPermissions.forEach {
        storageVolumePathsWeHaveAccessTo.add(it.uri.toString())
    }
    val storageManager = getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
    val storageVolumes = storageManager.storageVolumes

    for (storageVolume in storageVolumes) {
        val uuid = if (storageVolume.isPrimary) {
            // Primary storage doesn't get a UUID here.
            "primary"
        } else {
            storageVolume.uuid
        }
        val volumeUri = uuid?.let { buildVolumeUriFromUuid(it) }
        when {
            uuid == null -> 
                Log.d("AppLog", "UUID is null for ${storageVolume.getDescription(this)}!")
            storageVolumePathsWeHaveAccessTo.contains(volumeUri) -> 
                Log.d("AppLog", "Have access to $uuid")
            else -> Log.d("AppLog", "Don't have access to $uuid")
        }
    }
}

private fun buildVolumeUriFromUuid(uuid: String): String {
    return DocumentsContract.buildTreeDocumentUri(
        "com.android.externalstorage.documents",
        "$uuid:"
    ).toString()
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    Log.d("AppLog", "resultCode:$resultCode")
    val uri = data?.data ?: return
    val takeFlags =
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
    contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
    Log.d("AppLog", "granted uri: ${uri.path}")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
but what is Uri.parse(namedataprefs) in the code?

Comment: sir this saves the location in sharedpresf so it can be retrieved later

Answer (score 1):

For Fetch Whatsapp Status in Android 11 You have to Fetch this status from this path.
which is written below:-

Android->media->com.whatsapp->WhatsApp->Media->.Statues->"You can see all statues which was show by user"

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this Path. it may be helpful for you.**

For `Android-10` and above

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses")
```

Below `Android-10` Version

```
File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses")
```

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated in new Androids and `File` API cannot be used directly anymore on new Androids without very special permissions or user selecting it

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the simple steps:-

```
 private fun getFolderPermission() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val sm =
            requireContext().applicationContext.getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.STORAGE_SERVICE) as StorageManager
        val intent = sm.primaryStorageVolume.createOpenDocumentTreeIntent()
        val starDir = "Android%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
        var uri = intent.getParcelableExtra<Uri>("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI")
        var scheme = uri.toString()
        scheme=scheme.replace("/root/","/document/")
        scheme += "%3A$starDir"
        uri = Uri.parse(scheme)
        intent.putExtra("android.provider.extra.INITIAL_URI", uri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1234)

    }
    checkPermissions(0)
}

private fun checkPermissions(type: Int): Boolean {
    var result: Int
    val listPermissionNeeded: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()
    for (p in permissions) {
        result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), p)
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            listPermissionNeeded.add(p)
        }
    }
    if (listPermissionNeeded.isNotEmpty()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            (activity as Activity?)!!,
            listPermissionNeeded.toTypedArray(),
            type
        )
        return false
    } else {
        getData()
    }
    return true
}

private fun getData() {

    var targetPath =
        Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses"

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        targetPath =
            Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().absolutePath + "/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/.Statuses"
    }

    val targetDirector = File(targetPath)
    val allFiles = targetDirector.listFiles()

    try {
        list.clear()

        for (file in allFiles) {
            if (!file.name.endsWith(".nomedia")) {
                if (file.name.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    list.add(StatusModel(file.name, file.path))
                }
            }
        }
        setUpRecyclerView(list)
    } catch (e: Exception) {

        Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "" + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```