# How to get all files from a specific folder using its Uri in android 11

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to get all files from whatsapp status folder using Storage Access Framework. Inside on ActivityResult I got this Uri

```
content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses
```

I wants to know how to get all files from that folder using this URI in android 11 and above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WhatsApp Status Save In Android 11 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768384/whatsapp-status-save-in-android-11-or-above)

Comment: How did you obtain that uri to begin with? Which action?

Comment: For the rest it does not matter if the uri is from a whatsapp folder or that Android is 11+. How to list files from an uri tree is always the same.