# How to use .status folder for WhatsApp status saver app in android 11 scoped storage?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-11, scoped-storage

Hey guys I had made a WhatsApp status saver app. But in android 11, Google introduced scoped storage so I'm not getting status of the user in the app. For that I have used MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE but with this I can't publish the app in Google play. I've seen few apps using some permission to grant access to use that .status folder. How to do that ? I have attached the screenshot of the permission that the app was asking. I am a beginner so please help me out.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are number 100 who askes this the last year. Google a bit..

Comment: Bro i don't know what it exactly called...i have searched many times....can you please  give me google developer link for that..thank you

Comment: See this Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67768384/whatsapp-status-save-in-android-11-or-above

Comment: Thanks you Fenil...its really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Request the user to give permission to the WhatsApp status storage folder.

```
private void checkWhatsAppPermission(){
    // Choose a directory using the system's file picker.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
    // Optionally, specify a URI for the directory that should be opened in
    // the system file picker when it loads.

    Uri wa_status_uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia/document/primary%3AAndroid%2Fmedia%2Fcom.whatsapp%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses");
    intent.putExtra(DocumentsContract.EXTRA_INITIAL_URI, wa_status_uri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 10001);
}
```

You can check a working example using above method here.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.larntech.whatsappstatussaver

Comment: for me on Android 10 this "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AAndroid%2FWhatsApp%2FMedia%2F.Statuses"
uri worked.