# Getting permission of a particular folder

Tags: android-studio

I am using this new [code](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/d5h7vwkeqittgm6oruhag/WhatsApp.txt?rlkey=hlv9ozfcgox3dk43oobyuem55&dl=0) to get the folder permission but it shows this message [link](https://ibb.co/zSwg3PM)

Android Studio - Giraffe 2022.3.1 Android Device - Android 11

I was expecting to get the Solution to get the storage permission for the particular folder

Comment: check out this maybe it will help https://stackoverflow.com/q/67768384/12709358 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/57116787/12709358