# How to give to a service permission to read a Uri?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

**TL;DR**: I get the following error when I try to read a file (Uri) in a service I get the following error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider
```

---

**What I am trying to do**:

a) read an audio file at specific time

b) have the option to stop the Media Player using the app interface (stopService())

c) make sure that even if the app is closed, the audio still gets played

---

**How I am trying to do it**:

1. Select an audio file using ACTION_GET_CONTENT in Main Activity

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
     { result ->if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    val data: Intent? = result.data
                    fileUri = data?.data!!
                }
            }
    
    val myIintent = Intent()
                    .setType("audio/*")
                    .setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)

    resultLauncher.launch(myIntent)
```

2. Set an alarm using a pending intent AlarmManager, and pass the Uri (as a string) using extras to the AlarmManager

   ```
    val alarmIntent = Intent(context,AlarmSetter::class.java)
    alarmIntent.action = "SET_ALARM"
    alarmIntent.putExtra("audio_path",fileUri.toString())

    alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    var pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0)

    alarmManager.setAndAllowWhileIdle(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        pendingIntent)
   ```
3. Call the service in the receiver and pass the Uri to the service in the intent
   override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {

   ```
    val filePath = intent?.getStringExtra("audio_path")
    val musicIntent = Intent(context, MusicService::class.java)
    musicIntent.putExtra("audio_path",filePath)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context?.startForegroundService(musicIntent)}
    else{
        context?.startService(musicIntent)
    }
   ```
4. Read the file in the service

```
override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

       ...
       notification()
       ...

       val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(intent?.getStringExtra("audio_path")))

       ...
```

---

**Problem:**

When the App is still running, the service sends the notification is sent and the audio file is read by the media player.

However, when the app is killed/exited, the notification is sent but the file can't be read because the service does not have permission to open it.

Comment: Dont know. But for instance if you had used ACTION_VIEW for this uri you would have added a flag like grand read uri permission or such.

Comment: I'd just like to say that this question is VERY well-formatted and present, congrats!

Comment: @TomasMota I surely appreciate the compliment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `putExtra()` calls with `setData()` calls and add `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` to each of those outbound `Intent` objects. And, replace your `getStringExtra()` calls with `getData()` calls.

This will pass your `Uri` as an actual `Uri` in the "data" facet of the `Intent`, and it will pass along the read permission as you traverse process and component boundaries.

See [this blog post](https://commonsware.com/blog/2020/08/08/uri-access-lifetime-still-shorter-than-you-might-think.html) for more.

Comment: This is the correct answer, however it seems like you ALSO need to add the FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION flag.

Comment: Also, it seems like you only need to set permission flags in the receiver for the intent to the service, you don't need to set them in the (pending) intent from the Activity to the receiver.

Comment: @nayriz: "you ALSO need to add the FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION flag" -- AFAIK that would only be necessary if you are calling `takePersistableUriPermission()` in the recipient, rather than in the provider of the `Uri`. Personally, if I want persistable permission, I try to request that first thing before doing much else with the `Uri`. The `PendingIntent` might automatically be adding those flags on some versions of Android, but you should make sure that you test that on all versions that you support.

Comment: Interesting. I experimented with it and for me it doesn't work if it's not there the first time I use the app.

Comment: WARNING: the solution seems to work in SDK 26 but not in SDK 25. When adding the flags, startService crashes in the receiver.

Answer (score 0):

Based on CommonsWare's answer, and [one of his other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34664915/no-persistable-permission-grants-found-for-uri), this is what worked for me:

In step 1) set the intent action to **ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT** instead of ACTION_GET_CONTENT, and call takePersistableUriPermission()

```
val resultLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult())
         { result ->if (result.resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        val data: Intent? = result.data
                        fileUri = data?.data!!
                        this.contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
    filePath, FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    }
                }
    
val myIintent = Intent()
                .setType("audio/*")
                .setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
    
resultLauncher.launch(myIntent)
```

In step 2) instead of

```
alarmIntent.putExtra("audio_path",fileUri.toString())
```

do

```
alarmIntent.data = fileUri
```

In step 3) do:

```
val fileUri = intent?.data
val musicIntent = Intent(context, MusicService::class.java)

musicIntent.data = fileUri
```